# Laravel - When edit, the link for the file upload does not show

Tags: php, html, laravel

Only the edit link doesn't show as all the other fields show the data that is saved in the database. In the database I save the file name only as when the link is requested, I change it to save only the file name

```
 //this is code is in the RevisionsController

 if($request->hasFile('link')){
        $request->file('link');
        $request->link->store('public');
        $revision->link = $data . $request->link->store('public');
    }else{
        return 'No file Selected';
    }


//this file is the edit.blade.php for the revisions

<div class="panel-body">
    <form action="/revisions/{{ $revision->revision_id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="publication_id">Publication</label>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="publication_id">
                @foreach($publications as $publication)
                {{$found = false}}
                @if($publication->publication_id == $revision->publications['publication_id'])
                {{$found=true}}
                @endif
                @if($found)
                <option selected>{{$publication->name}}</option>
                @else
                <option>{{$publication->name}}</option>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edition">Publication Edition</label>
            <input type="text" style="background-color: #fff" name="edition" class="form-control"  value="{{$revision->edition}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="link">Upload Publication File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="link" value="Upload Publication" class="form-control"  value="{{$revision->link}}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <input type="submit" style="width: 150px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
        </div>          
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pre-fill the value of a `<input>` tag. If you want to show the current value to the user, think about displaying in a `<div>` before the input for example.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="link">Upload Publication File: ({{ $revision->link }})</label>
    <input type="file" name="link" value="Upload Publication" class="form-control"  value="{{$revision->link}}">
</div>
```

Comment: @Llope so there isn't another way to show the file in the input field by using  value?

Comment: You can't use value in an input field to pre-fill it, right.

Comment: I can't understand why there is two value tag in the input?